# Communication between ViewModel + View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui

I am new to Combine and am struggling with a few concepts around communication. I come from a web background and before that was UIKit, so a different landscape to SwiftUI.

I am very keen to use `MVVM` to keep business logic away from the `View` layer. This means that any view that is not a reusable component, has a `ViewModel` to handle API requests, logic, error handling etc.

The problem I have run into is what is the best way to pass events to the `View` when something happens in the `ViewModel`. I understand that a view should be a reflection of state, but for things that are event driven, it requires a bunch of variables that I think is messy and so keen to get other approaches.

The example below is a `ForgotPasswordView`. It is presented as a sheet, and when a successful reset occurs, it should close + show a success toast. In the case that it fails, there should be an error toast shown (for context the global toast coordinator is managed via an `@Environment` variable injected at the root of the app).

Below is a limited example

`View`

```
struct ForgotPasswordView: View {

    /// Environment variable to dismiss the modal
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    /// The forgot password view model
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ForgotPasswordViewModel = ForgotPasswordViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {
                    // Field contents + button that calls method
                    // in ViewModel to execute the network method. See `sink` method for response
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: self.closeButton /* Button that fires `closeSheet` */)
        }
    }

    /// Close the presented sheet
    private func closeSheet() -> Void {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`

```
class ForgotPasswordViewModel: ObservableObject {

    /// The value of the username / email address field
    @Published var username: String = ""

    /// Reference to the reset password api
    private var passwordApi = Api<Response<Success>>()

    /// Reference to the password api for cancelling
    private var apiCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        self.apiCancellable = self.passwordApi.$status
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] result in
            guard let result = result else { return }

            switch result {
            case .inProgress:
                // Handle in progress

            case let .success(response):
                // Handle success

            case let .failed(error):
                // Handle failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above `ViewModel` has all the logic, and the `View` simply reflects the data and calls methods. Everything good so far.

Now, in order to handle the `success` and `failed` states of the server response, and get that information to the UI, is where I run into issues. I can think of a few ways, but I either dislike, or seem not possible.

**With variables**

Create individual `@Published` variables for each state e.g.

`@Published var networkError: String? = nil`

then set them is the different states

```
case let .failed(error):
   // Handle failure
   self.networkError = error.description
}
```

In the `View` I can then subscribe to this via `onRecieve` and handle the response

```
.onReceive(self.viewModel.$networkError, perform: { error in
    if error {
        // Call `closeSheet` and display toast
    }
})
```

This works, but this is a single example and would require me to create a `@Published` variable for every state. Also, these variables would have to be cleaned up too (setting them back to nil.

This could be made more graceful by using an `enum` with associated values, so that there is only a single listener + variable that needs to be used. The enum doesn't however deal with the fact that the variable has to be cleaned up.

**With `PassthroughSubject`**

Building on this, I went looking at `PassthroughSubject` thinking that if I create a single `@Publisher` like

```
@Publisher var events: PassthoughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Event, Never>
```

And publish events like this:

```
.sink { [weak self] result in
            guard let result = result else { return }

            switch result {
            case let .success(response):
                // Do any processing of success response / call any methods
                self.events.send(.passwordReset)

            case let .failed(error):
            // Do any processing of error response / call any methods
                self.events.send(.apiError(error)
            }
        }
```

Then I could listen to it like this

```
.onReceive(self.viewModel.$events, perform: { event in
    switch event {
    case .passwordReset:
      // close sheet and display success toast
    case let .apiError(error):
      // show error toast
})
```

This is better that the variable, as the events are sent with `.send` and so the `events` variable doesn't need cleaning up.

Unfortunately though, it doesn't seem that you can use `onRecieve` with a `PassthroughSubject`. If i made it a `Published` variable but with the same concept, then I would run into the having to clean it up again issue that the first solution had.

**With everything in the view**

The last scenario, that I have been trying to avoid is to handle everything in the `View`

```
struct ForgotPasswordView: View {

    /// Environment variable to dismiss the modal
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    /// Reference to the reset password api
    @StateObject private var passwordApi = Api<Response<Success>>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {
                    // Field contents + button that all are bound/call
                    // in the view.
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: self.closeButton /* Button that fires `closeSheet` */)
            .onReceive(self.passwordApi.$status, perform: { status in
                guard let result = result else { return }
                    switch result {
                    case .inProgress:
                        // Handle in progress
                    case let .success(response):
                        // Handle success via closing dialog + showing toast
                    case let .failed(error):
                        // Handle failure via showing toast
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a simple example, but if there is more complex processing or data manipulating that needs to happen, I don't want that to be in the `View` as it is messy. Additionally, in this case the success / failure event perfectly matches the events that are needed to be handled in the UI, not every view would fall into that category though, so even more processing could need to be done.

I have run into this conundrum for nearly every view that has a model, if something happens in the `ViewModel` that is a basic event, how should it be communicated to the `View`. I feel like there should be a nicer way to do this, which also leads me to think I am doing it wrong.

That was a large wall of text, but I am keen to ensure that the architecture of the app in maintainable, easily testable, and views focus on displaying data and calling mutations (but not at the expense of there being lots of boilerplate variables in the `ViewModel`)

Thanks

Comment: Why use `.onReceive` for everything? the only thing you really need it for seems to be for dismiss. everything else can be handled in the ViewModel. The ViewModel is vaguely like the UIKit `UIViewController` and the `View` is vaguely like storyboard. It seems like you are expecting the `View` to do more than it should

Comment: The storybook + view controller comparison is cool! In this case though, the toast system cannot (at least not to my knowledge) be accessed from the view model. This is because it is an environment object, and you cannot pass environment objects into the view models constructor.

I had originally tried to make the toast system a singleton, but that broke the reactivity of the Publisher (the data would appear, but swift wouldn’t do anything with it)

Comment: By using a StateObject and then using environmentObject, the same instance is shared with all of the views in a way that is reactive and works.

If you know why a static shared instance of the toast system breaks reactivity and have any solutions I'd love to hear them :) 

I think it is because it is outside what SwiftUI tracks, but I wasn't able to work out why.

Comment: I don't know what your toast looks like But if you make it a `ViewModifier` that taps into UIKit to show it in the rootViewController. You can put it anywhere and it always shows up on the top

Comment: To be clear, the toast environment variable is a class that has `create` and `remove` as it's public methods, it then coordinates via a public read only toasts array that is fed into a `ToastCoordindatorView` that actually renders/animates them.

Keen to hear more about the `ViewModifier` solution, how would I call that from the `ViewModel`? :)

Comment: [A SwiftUI ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier) you access it just like you access the `navigationBar` methods. you can make it work with a `Bool` that presents the UIKit `UIViewController/UIViewControllerRepresentable` on the root view.

Comment: That is cool, I have used `ViewModifiers` before! I guess my confusion is that I have a system that works well for coordinating toasts, and it sounds like this system with the `ViewModifer` still requires the `View` to know when to show the toast. Yes that can be controlled by the `ViewModel`, but that is the same solution as variables solutions proposed above.

Comment: True but likely no different than presenting a toast in UIKit. especially when dealing with a sheet. It would be interesting how you present the toast modal over the sheet modal for the password reset screen.

Comment: Well you just found a bug hahah. How I was doing it was adding a `ZStack` at the root app level with my toast coordinator view sitting there. That worked for anything in the `NavigationStack` but you are right, not for the `Sheet`. While this was not the purpose of this ticket, still useful haha. I will look into using a view modifier hooking into a `UIViewController/UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Comment: You can use the `ZStack` in the `ViewModifer` too if you can put it in the outermost `View`. The problem comes up when you put it in an inner view. It will present just over that inner view.

Answer (score 4):

You can have the result of your reset password request delivered to a `@Published` property of your view model. SwiftUI will automatically update the associated view when the state changes.

In the following I wrote a password reset form similar to yours, with a view and an underlying view model. The view model has a `state` with four possible values from a nested `State` enum:

- `idle` as initial state or after the username has been changed.
- `loading` when the reset request is being performed.
- `success` and `failure` when the result of the reset request is known.

I simulated the password reset request with a simple delayed publisher which fails when an invalid username is detected (for simplicity only usernames containing *@* are considered valid). The publisher result is directly assigned to the published `state` property using `.assign(to: &$state)`, a very convenient way to [connect publishers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/assign(to:)) together:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

final class ForgotPasswordViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum State {
        case idle
        case loading
        case success
        case failed(message: String)
    }
    
    var username: String = "" {
        didSet {
            state = .idle
        }
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var state: State = .idle
    
    // Simulate some network request to reset the user password
    private static func resetPassword(for username: String) -> AnyPublisher<State, Never> {
        return CurrentValueSubject(username)
            .delay(for: .seconds(.random(in: 1...2)), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { username in
                return username.contains("@") ? State.success : State.failed(message: "The username does not exist")
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func resetPassword() {
        state = .loading
        Self.resetPassword(for: username)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$state)
    }
}
```

The view itself instantiates and stores the view model as `@StateObject`. The user can enter their name and trigger ask for a password reset. Each time the view model state changes a `body` update is automatically triggered, which allows the view to adjust appropriately:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ForgotPasswordView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = ForgotPasswordViewModel()
    
    private var statusMessage: String? {
        switch model.state {
        case .idle:
            return nil
        case .loading:
            return "Submitting"
        case .success:
            return "The password has been reset"
        case let .failed(message: message):
            return "Error: \(message)"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("Password reset")
                .font(.title)
            TextField("Username", text: $model.username)
            Button(action: resetPassword) {
                Text("Reset password")
            }
            if let statusMessage = statusMessage {
                Text(statusMessage)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func resetPassword() {
        model.resetPassword()
    }
}
```

The code above can easily be tested in an Xcode project.